# PHP interpreter dies during database.int/execute during file.api.php/file_save in fields/file/file.field.inc/file_field_presave

Tags: database, files

I Dont know what to say really.

At the top level, im calling entity_metadata_wrapper.save on a user entity.
This code has been in production for months
The issue is during the save of a portrait field in the user bundle.
This doesnt happen anywhere else in the site, which still works fine in general

The final behaviour is that the php interpreter just dies, with no error at all. There is no mysql error. just stops during the execute function call..

At this point it seems clear that its something to do with the mysql driver outside drupal, but with no error message im reaching the edge of my skillset here.

Ive been developing drupal sites for about three years, have many of them, and have had this site up production for months.

Help would be much appreciated!

Regards,

Christophler